# Finding the difference in dimension for Null Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $N(A + vv^T) = N(A) ∩ N(vv^T)$ where $N$ represents the null space. A is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. We know that $\mathrm{dim}(R(vv^T)) = 1$, and therefore $\mathrm{dim}(N(vv^T)) = n-1$. However, does anyone know why $\mathrm{dim}(N (A + vv^T
)) ≥ \mathrm{dim}(N (A)) − 1$ is true based on the facts given?

Answer (score 1):

Given , $N(A+vv^{T})=N(A)∩N(vv^{T})$
And, $dim(N(vv^{T}))=n-1$

$dim(N(A+vv^{T}))=dim(N(A)∩N(vv^{T}))=dim(N(A))+dim(N(vv^{T}))-dim(N(A)+N(vv^{T}))$

$\implies dim(N(A+vv^{T}))= dim(N(A))+(n-1)-dim(N(A)+N(vv^{T}))$

$\implies dim(N(A+vv^{T}))= dim(N(A))-1+(n-dim(N(A)+N(vv^{T})))$

Now, since , $N(A) $ and $N(vv^{T})$ are subspaces of some space $\mathbb{F}^{n}$ of dimension $n$.
So, $N(A)+N(vv^{T})$ is also subspace of $\mathbb{F}^{n}$.

Hence, $dim(N(A)+N(vv^{T}))\le n $

So, $dim(N(A+vv^{T}))\ge dim(N(A))-1$

Answer (score -1):

## Update

Actually the statement is true even without $N(A + vv^T) = N(A)$ $\cap$ $N(vv^T)$ or symmetric positive semidefiniteness as the following proof demonstrates. In fact this easily follows form [A learner's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3834202/527702) because while they prove $dim(N(A)$ $\cap$ $N(vv^T))\geq ndim(N(A))-1$, we know that $$N(A) \cap N(vv^T) \subseteq N(A + vv^T)$$

---

**Example**
As an example suppose $v=e_5=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, and $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

then $N(vv^T):=span(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4)$, $N(A):=span(e_4, e_5)$ and $N(A+vv^T):=span\left(e_4, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right)$
which is not the intersection of the first two and yet $dim(N(A+vv^T))=2\geq 1=dim(N(A))-1$.

---

This is a prescriptive proof. We will find an orthonormal basis $B$ of $N(A + \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T)$ with $|B|\geq dim(N(A))-1$

Let $k=dim(N (A))$. Let an orthonormal basis of the $N(A)$ be denoted by the set $\{a_1, a_2, a_3...a_{k}\}$. Firstly, if $\mathbf{v}\cdot a_i=0$ for all $a_i$, $B:=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_k\}$ and $|B|=k$. Let us assume this is not so. 
Then the following vector is non-zero: $$\mathbf{v_{\parallel}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}(\mathbf{v}\cdot a_i)\,a_i$$
Notice that $\mathbf{v_{\perp}} = \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v_{\parallel}}$ is such that for all $a_i$, we have $\mathbf{v_{\perp}}\cdot a_i=0$. 
Now the set $\{a_1, a_2, a_3...a_{k}, \mathbf{v_{\parallel}}\}$ is clearly linearly dependant but spans a subspace of dimension only $k$. We now drop any one of the $a_i$s, where $\mathbf{v}\cdot a_i\neq 0$, say $a_1$ was one such vector. Now we do a Gram Schmidt orthogonalization on $\{a_2, a_3...a_{k}, \mathbf{v_{\parallel}}\}$ to get a basis with $\mathbf{v_{\parallel}}$ in it. Consider the vectors in this new basis other than $\mathbf{v_{\parallel}}$, let's say $\{a'_1, a'_2, a'_3...a'_{k-1}\}$. Now each $a'_j$ is in $N(A)$ because $a'_j$ must be in the span of $\{a_2, a_3..., a_{k}, \mathbf{v_{\parallel}}\}$ and thus in the span of $\{a_1, a_2, a_3...a_{k}\}$. But since $a'_j\cdot\mathbf{v_{\parallel}}=0$, notice that $a'_j\cdot\mathbf{v} = a'_j\cdot(\mathbf{v_{\parallel}}+\mathbf{v_{\perp}}) = a'_j\cdot\mathbf{v_{\perp}}=0$. The last equality is true because $a'_j$ is in the span of $\{a_1, a_2, a_3...a_{k}\}$ and as we noted, $\mathbf{v_{\perp}}\cdot a_i=0$ for each $a_i$. These thus constitute $B$ and $|B|=k-1$

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Very unhelpful to not specify/comment.